# CarrierWave S3 URLs work in staging but not development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm using Rails with CarrierWave and S3. My staging environment is Heroku. My development environment is Mac OS.

I seem to be able to upload files just fine in all environments. The problem is that when I click on a link to any file I've uploaded, I get an Access Denied error.

Many files that have been uploaded in the past (before my involvement in the project) seem to work, it just seems to be the newly-uploaded files that can't be accessed. I checked my S3 bucket and the files are in fact there.

I have a development bucket and a staging bucket. Both buckets work fine in my staging environment, so the problem doesn't seem to lie with my buckets. It seems to be a problem with something in the development environment.

Any troubleshooting ideas are much appreciated.

**Edit**: I was mistaken that the files are making it to my S3 bucket when I perform the upload from the development environment. I don't get any errors but when I check the S3 bucket, my file is not there. Again, uploading works fine in staging. It's only broken in development.

Comment: Where Access Denied comes from? AWS keys in certain environment with a given bucket wrong?